# An exponential inequality

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, inequality, exponential-function

Assume $a(t)\geq 0$ and $b(t)\geq 0$.

i can show the following inequality

$\mid e^{-\int_0^ta(s)ds}-e^{-\int_0^tb(s)ds} \mid\leq T\max_{0\leq t \leq T}\mid a(t)-b(t)\mid$

by writing $\mid e^{-\int_0^ta(s)ds}-e^{-\int_0^tb(s)ds}\mid =\mid -\int_{\int_0^t b(s)ds}^{\int_0^ta(s)ds} e^{-\tau}d\tau\mid \leq\mid\int_0^ta(s)ds-\int_0^tb(s)ds\mid\leq T\max_{0\leq t \leq T}\mid a(t)-b(t)\mid$

but under same assumptions i want to get a similar inequality  for the following difference

$e^{\int_0^ta(s)ds}-e^{\int_0^tb(s)ds}$

unfortunately, in this case i couldn't use the above approach. My question is can you show that a similar inequality for the above difference. Please.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "a similar inequality"? Try taking $a \equiv c$, $b \equiv 0$, $T$ large to see that a completely analogous estimate can not hold.

Comment: @PhoemueX $T>0$ is a fixed number and by a "similar inequality", i mean that $\mid e^{\int_0^ta(s)ds}-e^{\int_0^tb(s)ds} \mid\leq K T\max_{0\leq t \leq T}\mid a(t)-b(t)\mid$, where $K>0$ is a constant

Comment: @mfl: Exactly, that was what I wanted to say (take $t = T$). One can only do what "math" (the OP) wants, if the constant $K$ is allowed to depend on $T$. But this makes the expression $K \cdot T$ redundant and/or misleading.

Answer (score 1):

For $a(s)=ns^{n-1}$ and $b(s)=0$ we have

$$e^{\int_0^ta(s)ds}-e^{\int_0^tb(s)ds}=e^{t^n}-1.$$

We have $$\max_{0\leq t \leq T}|a(t)-b(t)|=1.$$ So, the inequality

$$e^{t^n}-1\le K T \max_{0\leq t \leq T}|a(t)-b(t)|=KT$$ must holds for any $t\in[0,T].$ Thus, we must have, in particular,

$$e^{T^n}-1\le KT.$$

This is impossible, unless you allow $K$ to depend on $T.$ But I think this is not what you are looking for.

The inequality works in case you deal with negative exponents because $e^{-x}\le 1$ for $x\ge 0.$ But, if you allow positive exponents then $e^x$ goes to infinite as $x$ goes to infinite, and it is not possible to get control on $e^x-e^y$ in the way you are suggesting.